# How to point to custom stubs directory in mypy via MYPY environment variable or mypy_path variable

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have created a stub file and put it along side of the original file as suggested. However I get `missing library stubs or py.typed marker` error. I tried adding the stubs directory using `mypy_path` variable in my config file. Still getting the same error. Any suggestions?
This is how I am initiating mypy:

```
 mypy --namespace-packages  --explicit-package-bases --config-file <setup.cfg> <mypy_file_to_typehint>
```

My setup.cfg has the following:

```
[mypy]
mypy_path = <directory path>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to point the `mypy_path` to the stubs directory *containing the stub modules*, not to the stub modules themselves.

For example if you generated the stubs using stubgen for module "MODULE" like so: `stubgen -m MODULE -o stubs`, stubgen will then generate the stubs in `stubs/MODULE`.

In this case, using pyproject.toml as an example (it's the most modern way to configure tools that support it, and so it's recommended):

```
[tool.mypy]
mypy_path = "$MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR/stubs"
```

This assumes `stubs` is in the same directory as pyproject.toml. If it isn't, adapt the path as needed.

The value of `mypy_path` should work identically for setup.cfg.

Comment: Also, double check that you wrote `[tool.mypy]` and **not** `[tools.mypy]` like I did :facepalm: